# Hide a chart if no data

Tags: pentaho

We are setting a chart on pentaho report designer 5.3 and we want it to hide if no data is returned by the query , lined to that chart .

We have used , the :

```
=not(isemptydata())
```

in the visible style expression but it shows

```
chart_user_no_data_available
```

on the chart so it is not working .

So how to solve this issue , best regards

Comment: Not sure about 5.3, but in earlier versions the formula had to start with "=" character (the "equals" sign).

Comment: yeah you are right i forgot the "=" but i was using it and it 's not working